# How should I fork an AOSP application?

Tags: android, android-source

**Background**

I am working on a dialer application. I am willing to make the application opensource. I have tried hard to fork the AOSP dialer application ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/l-preview)).

However, I don't have previous experience forking an AOSP application. After several hours, I found it very difficult.

**Method Tried**

I am doing my work using Android Studio. I have copied the resources and source-code of the AOSP components as modules in my project. Dependencies could be resolved.

**Major Difficulties**

1. Too much dependencies. From the make file ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/l-preview/Android.mk)), the dialer depends on ContactsCommon ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/ContactsCommon/+/l-preview)), InCallUI([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/InCallUI/+/l-preview)), android-common ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/l-preview/common/)), vcard ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/vcard/+/l-preview)), etc.. I have tried resolving the dependencies by importing those modules. However, much more problems arisen.
2. There are permissions only able to be granted as system application.
3. There are methods only visible by system applications. They are hidden from user application.
4. String resources with duplicate names and product attributes. I have read that they should be handled at pre-compile time. However, is it possible to have them processed with Gradle?

**Goal**

My goal is to publish an enhanced dialer application similar to ExDialer ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.modoohut.dialer)). I am not making another dialer to replace the original dialer in a custom ROM.

Thus, many dependencies and permissions are not needed at all. I just don't know how to separate the *'System'* part and *'User'* part of an AOSP application.

**Proposed Method**

Most likely I would be copying and modifying the resources and source-code instead of forking the original AOSP dialer. Are their any better ways to fork an AOSP application thus to reuse the existing resources and source-code?

Comment: AFAIK the AOSP dialer needs to be built together with the Android platform. It's not designed to be built as a standalone application (unbundled, in Android parlance). This doesn't affect your ability to _fork_ it, it's just that you won't be able to build it standalone.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree that the AOSP dialer is not designed to be built alone. I am now treating it as a code reference instead.

Comment: @Gavin did you ever make any progress?

Comment: @Segfault, https://github.com/dangleon/customdialer seems to have pulled something like it off, but a) I don't know how he did it (so I can't update to newer versions of the AOSP dialer), and b) it doesn't include the caller log.